# Function passed to child is being interpreted as a string

Tags: reactjs, function, components, react-props

In React, I'm trying to get a value from a radio button transmitted from a child component to its parent. To this end I've created a function in the parent and passed it to the child as a prop:

```
handleOptionChange = e => {
  this.setState({
    selectedOption: e.target.value
  });
};

<RadioRental handleOptionChange="this.handleOptionChange" />;
```

This is what I have in the child:

```
class RadioRental extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-check">
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="react-tips"
            value="saloon"
            checked={this.props.selectedOption === "option_saloon"}
            onChange={this.props.handleOptionChange}
            className="form-check-input"
          />
          Saloon car
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This produces the following compilation error:

index.js: 1446 Warning: Expected`onChange` listener to be a function, instead got a value of`string` type.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `{}` notation in your parent:

```
<RadioRental handleOptionChange={this.handleOptionChange} />;
//------------------------------^-----------------------^
```

The `{}` notation sees things as JavaScript vs `""` is string attribute.

**Final Code**

```
handleOptionChange = e => {
  this.setState({
    selectedOption: e.target.value
  });
};

<RadioRental handleOptionChange={this.handleOptionChange} />;
```